# url rewrite leads to 404 not found for both urls

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I am trying to rewrite website.com/events/event_page.php?id={id} so that users can go to this URL: website.com/event/{id}

this is what I am trying:

```
RewriteRule ^event/([0-9]+)$ event_page.php?id=$1
```

Am I missing something? not only does it not redirect, but the original URL stops working at the same time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The folder `/events/` is missing, try this:

```
RewriteRule ^event/([0-9]+)$ /events/event_page.php?id=$1
```

Comment: thank you. i had tried that too but what i didnt realize what i deleted the original .htaccess which specified which version of php i was using, so that was my problem.